# Pass string as a parameter

Tags: javascript

I am passing string to a function but its giving me an error :

```
assignAttr(var menu="menu", var container="menu_container",var text="menu_text");

function assignAttr(menu,container,text)
{
 alert(menu + container + text);
}
```

Comment: Please take the time to at least read the basics about the language.  JavaScript looks nothing like the first line of code that you posted.

Answer (score 4):

You simply need to call the function like this:

```
assignAttr("menu", "menu_container", "menu_text");
```

Answer (score 2):

Proper code is like this:

```
function assignAttr(menu,container,text) { 
  alert(menu + container + text); 
}

var menu="menu";
var container="menu_container";
var text="menu_text";
assignAttr(menu, container, text);
```

The code serves the purpose of display how to use a variable as a parameter.

And of course you can write function call as:

```
assignAttr("menu", "menu_container", "menu_text");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not declare the variables like this. You need to do it like:

```
var menu="menu"; 
var container="menu_container";
var text="menu_text";

assignAttr(menu, container, text); 

function assignAttr(menu,container,text) 
{ 
 alert(menu + container + text); 
}
```

Comment: It won't work imho because you call a function that is defined after the call.

Comment: @MartyIX: The order of defining functions doesn't matter as long as they are in the same scope.